# How to check if I'm at the right URL in AppleScript (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript

I'm new to AppleScript and having trouble with this:

I'm creating a script for Chrome where I want to login to a site and check something for me. For now, I just need to check if I'm actually routed to the correct URL (sometimes I'm already logged in) or if I need to login (if the system has logged me out automatically). If I'm logged out, I just want to click the "Login" button (my credentials autofill). If I'm logged in already, then I'll just proceed with the rest of the script.

This is where I'm at:

```
activate application "Google Chrome"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    open location "URL"
--Check if I have to login or not
--If I do, click the button "login"
--If not, proceed.
--The rest.
end tell
```

I was thinking of either: 
1.) checking if I'm at the right URL and then if not, click the login button
or 2.) check for presence of the login button and click it if it's present

I would love some direction on which way is more efficient and how to accomplish it. Struggling now to find the right commands... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that opens the location, waits til it's done loading, checks the url for a particular string, and if it's there, presses a button using javascript.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    open location "http://somesite.com"
    set theTab to tab 1 of window 1
    repeat
        if (loading of theTab) is false then exit repeat
    end repeat
    set theURL to URL of theTab
    if theURL contains "login" then
        execute theTab javascript "document.getElementById('login-button').click();"
    end if
end tell
```

You'll need to change what string the script checks for in the url. 
You will also need to learn the button ID. Just browse the the source code (Menu View/Developer/) of the page to find that, and switch it out for 'login-button'. Look for a line like:

```
<button class="login submit" value="Login now" type="submit" id="login-button">
```